# Close an Option Menu programmatically

Tags: android, android-menu, android-optionsmenu

I got a menu with a single menu item. When the user clicks the menu icon in the action bar, I am choosing that menu item automatically for the user by overriding the `onMenuOpened()` like this:

```
@Override
public boolean onMenuOpened(int featureId, Menu menu)
{
    if(menu != null)
    {
        onOptionsItemSelected(menu.getItem(0));
        closeOptionsMenu();
    }
    return super.onMenuOpened(featureId, menu);
}
```

The issue here that the menu is not closing after it opens. So this menu item opens another fragment, and when the user back press to the original fragment in which he clicked the menu, it is still opened.

How do I close it?

Comment: try to add invalidateOptionmenu after selecting

Comment: didn't help... menu still showing when pressing back

Comment: you call menu item from fragment or activity?

Comment: The onCreateMenu and onOptionItemSelected is done at the activity level.

Comment: It's AppCompatActivity

Answer (score 0):

You can close the options menu programmatically with `closeOptionsMenu()`.

Now try to change the position of `closeOptionsMenu()`. Call it before `onOptionsItemSelected()`.

Link:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#closeOptionsMenu

Comment: Changing the position of the call did not help

Comment: ok, try one thing, call closeOptionsMenu() in your onOptionsItemSelected() function after doing the required operation rather than in onMenuOpened().

Comment: I tried calling before and after the action itself and the menu is still left open

Comment: What I am trying to say is that , call closeOptionsMenu() in your onOptionsItemSelected() implementation. Have u done that?

Comment: Yes. Added it there before and after the action itself which is being called there and it still did not help